# xampp and mongoDB : cannot recognize mongo driver

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I´m trying to add the driver for mongoDB in xampp(PHP).
xampp version is 3.2.1
with Current PHP version: 5.5.11

I placed the compatible php_mongo.dll(which was originally php_mongo-1.5.7-5.5-vc11.dll, so it is compattible with php 5.5) in the ext folder,
I added extension=php_mongo.dll to the end of my php.ini file

when I try to start the apache server using xampp,
xampp gives me the warning "PHP Startup:"(blank space)

and can't find the Mongo class, so the driver is not loading.

am I doing something wrong? Can I use something else besides xampp and easier?

Answer (score 0):

I did for Php 5.6, MongoDb 3.4, hope it will help to you

**Follow below steps to make Mongo work for PHP-5.6**

- goto https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.14/windows
- download php_mongo-1.6.14-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip
- extract the zip file and copy php_mongo.dll
- open PHP ext directory and paste the dll file
- add the following line to your php.ini file
  extension=php_mongo.dll
- restrat apache and test with below php code

  echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

  $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");

  echo "Connection to database successfully";

  $db = $m->testdb;     // where testdb is already existing Database

  echo "Database testdb selected";

**Note : Check the "mongo" module is loaded or not using phpinfo()**